# get the_content by ID and save the result to one array

Tags: get-posts, the-content

I try this:

```
<?php
    function get_ct($id){
        $ct = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
        return $ct;
    }

    $arr = array('post_content' => get_ct(126));

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

but the post_content 's values ist null any suggestion? thanks

Comment: `apple_filters` is expecting a callable/function as a second parameter, but you're passing in a value. Also which file is this running in?

Comment: I think Tom means `apply_filters`

Comment: @TomJNowell you're thinking of `add_filter`. `apply_filters` is being used more or less correctly in the snippet above.

Comment: The code executes for me, I would double-check that your post #126 has post_content data and isn't trashed or set to private.

Comment: i need to send data of post content in json format via ajax .. that is the problem

Comment: `<?
function get_the_content_by_id($post_id) {
    $page_data = get_page($post_id);
    if ($page_data) {
    $content = $page_data->post_content;
    return $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    }
    else return false;
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

   $arr = array('post_content'=> get_the_content_by_id(126));
    echo json_encode($arr);

?>` output

`{"post_content":"<p><iframe src=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/2MpUj-Aua48\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"><\/iframe><\/p>\n"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_content()` to fetch the post content, e.g.:

```
$content = get_the_content( $post_id );
```

Then you can pass it through `the_content` filter and json encode

However, based on your comments, it looks like you're creating an endpoint for AJAX calls that returns post content. Don't bother! WordPress comes with one out of the box!

e.g.

```
https://tomjn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/848
```

The response has a `content` field and even contains a `rendered` version that contains a fully rendered post as you desired.

You don't need to do anything to get this, it's already on your site at `/wp-json`

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
function postData($id){
    $p_data = get_post($id);
    if ($p_data) {
    $content = $p_data->post_content;
    return $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

:)

Comment: Could you explain why is this the solution for given question? (And what the question really was?)

Comment: I needed, save the content of a post in one array.. the code above work's 
`header("Content-Type: application/json");
$arr = array('post_content'=>postData(126));
echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: based on that comment, you can probably just use the REST API rather than writing your own endpoint, e.g. https://tomjn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/848